# How to set the logging directory dynamically in Log4J2 by using service loader services?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I know that in Log4j2 you can set the logging directory dynamically by using something like:

```java
System.setProperty('logDirectory', getLogDirectoryDynamically());
```

and use this value in Log4j2's configuration:

```xml
<File name="File" fileName="${sys:logDirectory:-.}/my.log" append="false">
...
</File>
```

Okay, but now assume, for whatever reasons you do NOT have a central location (for example no `main` method of a main class) where you can invoke `System.setProperty('logDirectory', ...)`.

Is there a way that you can register some (java.util.ServiceLoader) services where you can add this `logDirectory` as property, maybe by implementing the `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource` interface or something similar?

The aim is that at the first `LogManager.getLogger(...)` invocation your additional property source will be loaded by `java.util.ServiceLoader` which contains the value for `logDirectory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`PropertySource`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-api/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/PropertySource.html) service is not used in a configuration file.

What you can implement is [`StrLookup`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-core/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrLookup.html). Lookups are not detected through the normal `ServiceLoader` mechanism, but through Log4j's plugin mechanism, so you need to annotate the class with:

```java
@Plugin(name = "mylookup", category = StrLookup.CATEGORY)
```

and compile it with the annotation processor contained in `log4j-core` (most of the time it is automatically detected).

Once you have done that you can use:

```xml
<File name="File" fileName="${mylookup:logDirectory:-.}/my.log" append="false">
...
</File>
```

in your config file.

**Remark**: the name of the lookup must be all lowercase.

Comment: You're the best! Even with my question being vague and pointing in the wrong direction, you've nonetheless showed me exactly the solution I was desperately looking for. Thank you very much. By the way, in my case the annotation processor was not necessary (as you have already assumed), guess Log4j's doing some classpath scanning.

Comment: Normally Log4j only uses the `Log4j2Plugins.dat` file that is generated by the annotation processor during compilation. It does not scan the classpath unless you set a `packages` attribute on the `<Configuration>` element. Disclaimer: I am an Apache Logging Services PMC, so knowing these things comes with the job. ;-)